# Get an alert when a form cant be submitted using ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a form for a user to request a day off, on my server side i have functionality to check if more than 3 people have asked for that same day off and if they have it wont let the user request that day. I want to display a pop up/alert when they cant request that day

This is in my method in my controller

```
if(results.size() >3)
{
   System.out.println("Too many people asked for that day off");
   return new ModelAndView("request");

}
else
{
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setDate(newDate);
    request.setNumDays(numDays);
    request.setReason(reason1);

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("successRequest");
    mv.addObject("request", request);

    requestService.save(request);
        return mv;
}
```

It return an empty form when there is more than 3 requests for that day but i also want it to have an alert message 
Ive tried to do it on my jsp page using ajax

```
$('#form').submit(function(e)
{   
     $.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:"/request",
     data:$(this).serialize(),
     error: function(){
      window.alert("Too many people have asked for that day off");
      console.log("Error");
     }
});     
});
```

Comment: In your controller code you are only printing out the message to the console, you are not sending it back to browser. Add code to send it back as part of the request as you are sending in your “else” part

Comment: @LearningPhase how do i display it in an alert box then once ive sent it back to the browser? The form refreshes and I want an alert box to pop up

Comment: In your browser code your ajax call has an error bur no success block. Check the below link http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-ajax-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is expecting `JSON` response not `ModelAndView` Object.

So First things to do is to return JSON Response using `@ResponseBody` instead of `ModelAndView` Object.

Then based on the flag value you can show the alert to user.

Comment: how would I return a json response? I am new to ajax